# How to draw rectangular shapes canvas view using CustomPainter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to draw a canvas rectangular lines for the call recording. How do I draw it using `customPainter`? Is there a better approach?

[image]

Comment:  You can use the touchable library https://github.com/nateshmbhat/touchable , to add gestures to each individual rectangles you draw on your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CustomPainter

```
class YourRect extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 50.0),
      new Paint()..color = new Color(0xFF0099FF),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(YourRect oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
new GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    debugPrint("hello");
  },
  child: Container(
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    child: CustomPaint(
      painter: (YourdrawRect()),
    ),
  ),
),
```